# Material Theme Colors results in blank Jetpack Compose Button

Tags: android, material-design, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

A simple composable with default Material Theme colors (code below) results in the following preview image (both in IDE and on device)

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewCalendar() {
  MaterialTheme {
    Column{
      Row{Text("Hello World")}
      Row{Button(onClick = {}){Text("Hello World Button")} }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Default colors for Material Theme]

When providing my own colors, then the button becomes blank (code and screenshot below). Reading through source for `Button` I would have expected the button to have `primary` as the background color.  Have I implemented my colors incorrectly? I could not find a bug report for similar behavior

```kotlin
val lightTheme = 
  Colors(
    primary = Color(0x0d47a1),
    primaryVariant = Color(0x5472d3),
    secondary = Color(0x212121),
    secondaryVariant = Color(0x484848),
    background = Color(0xffffff),
    surface = Color(0xffffff),
    error = Color(0xB00020),
    onPrimary = Color(0xffffff),
    onSecondary = Color(0xffffff),
    onBackground = Color(0x000000),
    onSurface = Color(0x000000),
    onError = Color(0xffffff),
    isLight = true
  )

@Preview
@Composable
fun PreviewCalendar() {
  MaterialTheme(colors = lightTheme) {
    Column{
      Row{Text("Hello World")}
      Row{Button(onClick = {}){Text("Hello World Button")} }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Custom colors for Material Theme]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I generated these colors using google's material theme tools, but did not notice that Compose was looking for ARGB color space. All the colors that I specified had an alpha value of 0, and were therefore transparent. The correct colors are:

```kotlin
val lightTheme = 
  Colors(
    primary = Color(0xFF0d47a1),
    primaryVariant = Color(0xFF5472d3),
    secondary = Color(0xFF212121),
    secondaryVariant = Color(0xFF484848),
    background = Color(0xFFffffff),
    surface = Color(0xFFffffff),
    error = Color(0xFFB00020),
    onPrimary = Color(0xFFffffff),
    onSecondary = Color(0xFFffffff),
    onBackground = Color(0xFF000000),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF000000),
    onError = Color(0xFFffffff),
    isLight = true
  )
```